# You don't gotta be so rude. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

**You don't gotta be so rude.**

What does it mean?

Does It mean "You shouldn't be so rude"??

Most of the native speakers use **gotta** in their conversation.

Can **Gotta** be used instead of **Should**?

Comment: You have only to google **gotta** to discover that it's informal English (slang) for **got/have to**, as you surmise. The question is less **can you use it** than when it is appropriate to use it.

Answer (score 6):

As a learner, you should take great care in using this kind of informal language. Many people will consider it to be a mistake.  If a native speaker uses this kind of language it might be thought to be a particular cultural style or cant.

But English learners are not members of this language group. Unless you have picked up this kind of slang "naturally" (by being integrated into a culture) it just sounds odd.

"Don't gotta" is a proscibed slang form of "Don't have to"  (there is a sense transfer from "have" to "got") So it means "You don't have to be so rude" or "You are able to be more polite".  It implies "You are being rude and you should be more polite".

If you are not sure if it is appropriate to use this kind of slang form, then avoid.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

"gotta" is common slang for "have to". Note that "You don't should be so rude" doesn't make sense. "You don't have to be so rude" makes sense, though.

The slang is quite common, although the sounds kind of slur together when I hear it usually.

Note: since it's slang, I wouldn't necessarily use it in a business situation, but it's pretty common pretty much anywhere else. You won't have issues if you use "have to", and you can slowly pick up when it's appropriate. The important part is knowing it exists.

Comment: _You don't hafta_ (note pronunciation with /ft/, not /vt/) is normal colloquial English. In writing, it would be spelled _you don't have to_, and it would be normal. _You don't gotta_, on the other hand, is definitely not normal or colloquial, but rather a local or personal dialect that would be understood as equivalent to _you don't hafta_.

Comment: Hm, maybe. I think "gotta" is used more in positive contexts, as in "I gotta go to work now" which should be written "I have to go to work now"

Comment: _You don't gotta be so rude_ is hardly a positive context; and _gotta_ should not "be written" _have to_. They're two different constructions, not translations of each other.